# JFrame attached on the side of another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to attach a JFrame to another JFrame, it works by setting the coordinates of the 2nd jframe to the right edge of the first. But it doesn't feel like one whole because when I drag the first JFrame the second one lags behind it like a dog.

Is there any way to keep them from seperating when you drag it, so it looks more like one whole?

[image: jframes]

Comment: Use a `JSplitPane` (or any of a handful of other ways to include multiple GUI elements in the same general area) instead.  Those 'sticky frames' are weird.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but I like the 'sticky frames' :)

Comment: In that case, good luck & please assure me you will offer the end user the option to 'unstick' them.

Answer (score 3):

Because the host's heavyweight peer component owns the frame, this will be difficult to do in a cross-platorm manner. On Mac OS X, you might look at binding to [*Cocoa Drawers and Disclosure*](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.16/16.09/DrawersandDisclosure/index.html). The [MacWidgets](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/) project may have useful examples. See also this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489916/does-java-allow-you-to-use-native-ui-widgets-on-mac-os-x).

Answer (score 1):

Try a `JSplitPane` or a `JInternalFrame`, `JInternalFrame` provides many features of a native frame.