# Java create Mac panel

Tags: java, swing, window

How do I create a Mac panel type window in Java? A picture of a panel type window can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Windows/Windows.html). I found something about Window.Type, but that's Java 7 and I am using Java 6.

Basically under examples (in the link) there is an image of a Panel. Notice how the close/minimize/maximize bar is smaller than the other ones.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want as it is not clear from your link. See for example the screenshots in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/about-swing-and-jtable/5630271#5630271) illustrating how a standard `JFrame` looks on the Mac. To me, that looks the same as the images you linked to

Comment: @Robin In examples it has a picture of a Panel. The close/minimize/maximize bar is smaller.

Comment: See also `MacWidgets`, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7720887/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option has been available since J2SE 5:

```
// makes the buttons smaller and title bar thinner
frame.getRootPane().putClientProperty("Window.style", "small");
// removes the shadow around the window
frame.getRootPane().putClientProperty("Window.shadow", Boolean.FALSE);
```

More information on that and other similar tricks: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2007/tn2196.html#WINDOWS

Unfortunately it seems to be really hard to find an updated list of all these since Apple themselves stopped caring.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Mac Look and feel from the library http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/

I hope you wanted to make a panel/window look like Mac. Otherwise please add more details about what you are looking for.

Comment: You can create a JFrame with quaqua look and feel, to achieve close/minimize/max bar similar to mac.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to get mac style windows unless you run it on a mac (or if you use a custom build library). There is some sort of licensing issue with this, I remember looking into doing it back when using java 1.4.

Comment: In that case, set the look and feel to javax.swing.plaf.mac.MacLookAndFeel

Answer (score -2):

You can use something like this to get the default system appearance for each platform i.e. looks like a mac on mac devices, looks like standard window in windows

```
 UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

You will need to surround this in try/catch block. See [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) or [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) for further info

Comment: This is not needed as windows on mac are like this by default.