# Selecting an X window

Tags: java, linux, xorg

Is there any way to select an OS window in Java under Xorg?

Essentially I'd like to replicate the functionality of a command like xwininfo, but I'd like to avoid executing it as a child process if possible. As for the actual information needed, I'm looking for the position and size (x, y, width, height) of a window selected by the user, preferably (as with xwininfo) via the mouse, but searching by name would be acceptable as well.

As far as I know this functionality doesn't exist in the standard JDK, but a premade library or some reasonably straightforward JNA code would be perfect. Compatibility is only needed with recent versions of Linux / Xorg.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible without JNI/JNA coding. But there are libraries that already did this. Take a look on SWT. It probably can do what you need. Take a look on this thread: [Does Java allow you to use native UI widgets on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489916/does-java-allow-you-to-use-native-ui-widgets-on-mac-os-x)
It may be helpful.

Take a look on [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) too. I have never tried it but it seems exactly what you need.